# How do backspace and delete work in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

How do the backspace and delete keys work in CKEditor? If I have an iframe in the editable area, and have my cursor next to it, hitting backspace/delete deletes the iframe/removes its HTML code from there.

What I was unable to get was where is the code for this behavior? Where on hitting backspace the range is shrunken to the iframe and it was removed.

Please point me in the right direction of where this happens in the source code.

Comment: here in ck editor backspace and delete works properly...

Comment: i know..  my question was how does it work, where was teh code for it. i was unable to locate that.  :(

Answer (score 1):

There is something about delete

> oKeystrokeHandler.SetKeystrokes

But i don't about that behavior

```
var FCKEnterKey = function( targetWindow, enterMode, shiftEnterMode, tabSpaces ) 
{
   this.Window         = targetWindow ;
   this.EnterMode      = enterMode || 'p' ;
   this.ShiftEnterMode   = shiftEnterMode || 'br' ;

   // Setup the Keystroke Handler.
   var oKeystrokeHandler = new FCKKeystrokeHandler( false ) ;
   oKeystrokeHandler._EnterKey = this ;
   oKeystrokeHandler.OnKeystroke = FCKEnterKey_OnKeystroke ;

   oKeystrokeHandler.SetKeystrokes( [
      [ 13      , 'Enter' ],
      [ SHIFT + 13, 'ShiftEnter' ],
      [ 8         , 'Backspace' ],
      [ CTRL + 8   , 'CtrlBackspace' ],
      [ 46      , 'Delete' ]
   ] ) ;

   this.TabText = '' ;

   // Safari by default inserts 4 spaces on TAB, while others make the editor
   // loose focus. So, we need to handle it here to not include those spaces.
   if ( tabSpaces > 0 || FCKBrowserInfo.IsSafari )
   {
      while ( tabSpaces-- )
         this.TabText += '\xa0' ;

      oKeystrokeHandler.SetKeystrokes( [ 9, 'Tab' ] );
   }

   oKeystrokeHandler.AttachToElement( targetWindow.document ) ;
}
```

http://code.google.com/p/easyfckeditor/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/oh/how/easy/fck/js/fckeditor/editor/_source/classes/fckenterkey.js?r=2

Comment: i had seen the code for enter key...
its the delete and backspace code that im unable to find.. 
i checked the keystrokehandler, it has some special key behaviours defined, but there is none for backspace or delete..  :(